# Where is a great place to introduce some constants into a project?

Tags: ember.js

I would love to remove all the magic numbers inside my project, so I think import a constant to where they need to be is a great idea.

See my constant declaration below,

```
export default { validation: validation };

const validation = {
  password: 6,
  email: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
};
```

However when I try to import the constant into a component I get a import error which state the model could not be found.

Inside my component,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { validation } from '../../../../config/constants';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['login-panel'],
  // ...
}
```

My question is where is a good place to store this kind of constants and how to import into it to the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create util file by running `ember g util constants` and include configuration and where you require import it,

utils/constants.js

```
export default { validation: validation };

const validation = {
  password: 6,
  email: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
};
```

Importing like the below,

```
import { validation } from 'app-name/utils/constants';
```

Comment: I have no error while importing the util. However when I try to access the value I got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
`

Comment: I have also try to console log the imported `validation` from `init` callback which is `undefined`.

Comment: I have try to change the way of exporting to some like code at bottom of question. `init` hook do print the `dict` however when I try to access `validation` it shows `Cannot read property 'password' of undefined`

Comment: Found the error is because of the variable name collision.

Comment: glad you got it. if anything wrong in answer please feel free to update it.